# Discord error cannot read property 'isFocused'

Tags: javascript, properties, discord

I have some problem while launching Discord. Here is the error message: 
Uncaught exception:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFocused' of null[(@see Error message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFU99.jpg)

Can you help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has nothing to do with programming. Although discord has API's in multiple languages, the OP isn't using any of them. Instead, the OP is having trouble opening the discord.exe application, the application was throwing that error. Just like how "I'm having trouble opening chrome" is also off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the folder called discord in WIN+R -> %appdata%. After Closing the error it will automaticly download itself. Sign in and there you go

Comment: This worked immediately. Excellent and concise answer

Comment: I did this and it's still broken.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter this issue on Linux with Discord installed via Snap, the answer is simply removing `~/snap/discord` and rerunning Discord.
Also, make sure Discord was closed before this or you will need to redo this process.